# How to test dataframes are equal when one is from JSON?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes. One loaded from parquet, the other generated from a dictionary in JSON.

I keep getting this error even though the indexes are the same i.e. 0-5.

```
E           AssertionError: DataFrame.index are different
E           
E           DataFrame.index classes are not equivalent
E           [left]:  RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)
E           [right]: Index(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'], dtype='object')
```

does anyone know what i'd have to do to the right or left dataframe to get this to work?

the line is

```
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(de_df.head(), pd.DataFrame(expected_de_json))
```

Comment: Their indexes are different. As you can see, one is a RangeIndex, so the values are dynamically generated, while the other is just simple index, where the values are all essentially hard-coded.

Comment: thank you! makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset their indexes.

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Under some conditions, pandas will reset the index, but store the old index in a new column. `drop=True` will ensure that this does not happen.

Comment: That'd be redundant for `left`, wouldn't it? since the new index would be a `RangeIndex(5)`, right?

Comment: I need to remember to use that `drop=True` more often

Comment: Yes @wjandrea, of course, but just to be safe :)